# Out-of-memory failure handling method

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm implementing a function and i want it to be a "library quality" function:

```
char** str_cat(char** const  str, const char * const other ){

    if(str==NULL) 
        return NULL;
    if(other==NULL) 
        return str;
    if(*str==NULL) 
        return str_cpy(str,other);

    char* tmp=(char*)calloc(1,strlen(*str)+strlen(other)+1);
    if(tmp==NULL) 
            return NULL;
    strcat(strcpy(tmp,*str),other); 
    *str=tmp;
    return str;     
}
```

This is a version of strcat() function (different signature) and handles any extreme use cases.
But, my out-of-memory failure handling method would not be good for a large application making heavy use of a rich str_xxx() API library.

Question: Is there a better solution?

Comment: What do you mean "would not be good"? Also, I think you have some memory leaks?

Comment: @Xymostech: Memory leaks- I guess that the problem is that i'm not freeing the first argument and allocating a new block. If so, since the first argument is char** (pointer to a string), and moreover it maybe a pointer to code segment string i chose not to deal with it.

Comment: Well if you're worrying about out-of-memory conditions before you're worrying about memory leaks, then I think you have your priorities mixed up.

Comment: @Xymostech: "would not be good" - i think maybe there is a better solution on a low level.

Comment: In my definition of the API, this is a user irresponsibility to free that block (again: this is char** the original block pointer is not lost, and moreover, i can't free code segment block :) ).

Comment: If you're not freeing the original, you shouldn't be updating it (it would be lost to the caller if they didn't keep a copy of it, which would make your API a pain to use).

Comment: @Mat: 
char* s = "string";
char** sp = &s;
str_cat(sp, "otherString");

So, s wasn't lost for the caller. sp was updated.

Comment: That's exactly what I told you. Caller needs a copy of that pointer.

Comment: Better would be: the function does not alter or free the strings given as arguments, but returns a freshly allocated string consisting of the concatanation of it's arguments (or NULL on error)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a wrapper for `malloc`, let's say `xmalloc` (or some equivalent for `calloc`), that returns `NULL`, making the out-of-memory condition a responsibility of the application - or terminates the application. The former is a good choice for a robust, portable library. In the context of a modern operating system however, the latter is quite reasonable; the app is in serious trouble when an OOM error occurs, and probably can't recover anyway. `xmalloc` could attempt to perform some cleanups, save critical data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Better not alter or free the arguments but return a freshly allocated string instead:

```
char * mycatcat(char *one, char *two)
{
size_t len1, len2;
char *new;

if (!one && !two) return NULL;
len1 = (one) ? strlen (one) : 0;
len2 = (two) ? strlen (two) : 0;

new = malloc(1+ len1+ len2);
if (!new) return NULL;

if (len1) memcpy (new, one, len1);
if (len2) memcpy (new+len1, two, len2);
new[len1+len2] = 0;

return new;
}
```

BTW: this function should work also if the strings one or two are *not* obtained by malloc(); and thus *should not be freed*. Such that

```
char *onetwo;
onetwo = my_catcat( "eins", "zwo");
```

should work. (add const to the arguments for extra fun)

Comment: Nice and elegant. But: If only one of the arguments is NULL i am returning the other (not NULL) string as a new allocated string. Secondly, and the most important, out-of-memory failure handling is the same as mine and i'm looking for some alternatives :)

Comment: You could easily redefine your function as a wrapper around this one. You could even maintain the leaks.

Comment: BTW: if you look carefully, you can see that the above code returns a copy of "the other" string if one of the arguments is NULL. (and NULL if both are NULL)

Comment: What do you think if, I wouldn't return NULL no matter what. If both are NULL I return empty string.

Comment: You could do that, but what should you do if you could not allocate memory for the empty string?

Comment: Actually the question is about that case (and not only for empty string) :) . I think that a got some clue from the second answer. If we are talking about large application that making heavy use of a rich str_xxx() API library, this a good solution to exit with error.